# rsync --delete-after issues

Tags: synchronization, rsync

Running on an OSX 10.9 box. In a bash terminal I am trying to copy files from dir `a` to dir `b`, deleting the files from dir `a` as they are copied over.

I am using the following command:

```
rsync -av --delete -after /a/* /b
```

The files from `a` copy over to `b`, but the files in `a` are still there after the transfer.

Comment: What has python to do with this question?

Answer (score 12):

That's not what `--delete` does. `--delete` (and its variations like `--delete-after`) don't delete files from the source `a`, they delete files from the target `b` that do not exist in the source. The argument you are looking for is `--remove-source-files`.

Try `rsync -av --remove-source-files /a/ /b/`

Comment: Thank you. but this option just delete files. Now, How to delete directories with files?

Answer (score 2):

If you are at all worried about inadvertently removing directories that didn't transfer correctly when using (from the previous post)

> rm -rf /a/*

then you can use a slightly safer way of removing the empty sub-directories with 'find'.

```
rsync -av --remove-source-files /a/ /b/  && find /a/ -type d -empty -delete
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
rsync -av --remove-source-files /a/ /b/ && rm -rf /a/*
```

Comment: why the extra rm -rf?  versus the @StvnW answer without this step?  does this clean up empty dirs?

Comment: rm -rf removes everything, including empty (non empty too) directories